# Freeing two dimensional array of stack

Tags: c

This is the edited code:

I have a two dimensional stack, like

```
#define push(s,ele) s.list[++(s.last)]=ele

typedef struct vp {
    short int v1,v2;
}VPTYPE;  

typedef struct VPLIST{
    int last;
    VPPTR *list;
}VPLISTTYPE,*VPLISTPTR ;    

VPLISTPTR v1v2;  
v1v2=(VPLISTPTR)malloc(sizeof(VPLISTTYPE)*nof);  
a=0;
while(a<100)
{  //allocation part
   for(i=0;i< nof;i++)  
   {  
      v1v2[i].list=(VPPTR *)malloc(20*(sizeof(VPPTR)));  

     for(i2=0;i2< 10;i2++) //please note that I am not filling the array completely, in the actual code the value 10 is dependent on certain factors, which I am omitting for the sake of simplicty 
     {  
         v=(VPTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(VPTYPE));  
         push(v1v2[i],v); 
         v1v2[i]->v1=1;v1v2[i]->v2=2;
     }
   }
   // some algorithm goes on here which accesses these values in the stack

   // free memory part
  for(i=0;i< nof;i++)  
   {  
      for(i2=0;i2<= (v1v2[i2].last);i2++)
     {  
         free(v1v2[i2].list[i]); 
     }
   }

   a++;
}
```

When I free the memory this way there is memory leakage. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `v1v2[i].list= (VPPTR *)malloc((20))*((unsigned)sizeof(VPPTR));` looks a bit weird. You mixed the `(` and `)` I think. Try : `v1v2[i].list= (VPPTR *)malloc( 20 * (unsigned)sizeof(VPPTR) );` Although I don't see how the casts are useful.

Comment: You will eventually need to keep track of how many items *can* be stored in your stacks, so that you don't overflow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are not initializing the allocated memory in the code you show.  In general, you get non-zero garbage allocated by `malloc()`.  If you need zeroed memory, use `calloc()`.
- There's also the problem identified by [JCooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666402/jcooper)'s answer.
- There's also the problem identified by [Muggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418748/muggen)'s comment.
- You are freeing the items on the stack, but not the stacks as a whole.  That should be done inside the '`for (i2 = 0; ...)`' loop but after the '`for (k2 = 0; ...)`' loop.

Collectively, these add up to a minor catastrophe.

---

After the code edit...

- The type VPPTR is not defined, but is presumably meant to be '`typedef VPTYPE *VPPTR;`.
- In the struct VPLIST, you have a pointer to a VPPTR - one more reason to distrust such pointer typedefs.  You almost certainly intended to have a simple VPPTR there.  However, the other code does assume you need an array of pointers to pointers, so it is self-consistent (up to a point).
- This problem propagates into the memory allocation code.
- In your free memory loop, in the call to `free()`, you have reversed the roles of `i` and `i2`:

  ```
  free(v1v2[i2].list[i]);  // Yours
  free(v1v2[i].list[i2]);  // Mine
  ```
- Your assignments in the allocation loop (`v1v2[i]->v1=1;v1v2[i]->v2=2;`) are bogus.

---

The following code compiles clean and runs clean:

```
$ cc -Wall -Wextra -g -O3 -std=c99 x.c -o x
$ valgrind ./x
==16593== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==16593== Copyright (C) 2002-2006, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16593== Using LibVEX rev 1658, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==16593== Copyright (C) 2004-2006, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==16593== Using valgrind-3.2.1, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==16593== Copyright (C) 2000-2006, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16593== For more details, rerun with: -v
==16593== 
==16593== 
==16593== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 5 from 1)
==16593== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==16593== malloc/free: 2,201 allocs, 2,201 frees, 40,032 bytes allocated.
==16593== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==16593== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.
$
```

#### Working Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define push(s, ele) ((s).list[((s).last)++] = (ele))

typedef struct vp
{
    short v1;
    short v2;
} VPTYPE;

typedef struct VPLIST
{
    int     last;
    VPTYPE **list;
} VPLISTTYPE;

enum { nof = 2 };

int main(void)
{
    VPLISTTYPE *v1v2 = (VPLISTTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(*v1v2) * nof);

    for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
        v1v2[i].last = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
    {
        //allocation part
        for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
        {
            v1v2[i].list = (VPTYPE **)malloc(20 * sizeof(*v1v2[i].list));

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
            {
                VPTYPE *v = (VPTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(*v));
                v->v1 = 1;
                v->v2 = 2;
                push(v1v2[i], v);
            }
        }

        // free memory part
        for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
        {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < (v1v2[i].last); i2++)
            {
                free(v1v2[i].list[i2]);
            }
            free(v1v2[i].list);
            v1v2[i].list = 0;
            v1v2[i].last = 0;
        }
    }
    free(v1v2);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Simpler Working Code

This code uses one less level of indirection - and one less level of memory allocation, therefore - and compiles and runs equally cleanly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define push(s, ele) ((s).list[((s).last)++] = (ele))

typedef struct vp
{
    short v1;
    short v2;
} VPTYPE;

typedef struct VPLIST
{
    int     last;
    VPTYPE *list;
} VPLISTTYPE;

enum { nof = 2 };

int main(void)
{
    VPLISTTYPE *v1v2 = (VPLISTTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(*v1v2) * nof);

    for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
        v1v2[i].last = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
    {
        //allocation part
        for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
        {
            v1v2[i].list = (VPTYPE *)malloc(20 * sizeof(*v1v2[i].list));

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
            {
                VPTYPE v;
                v.v1 = 1;
                v.v2 = 2;
                push(v1v2[i], v);
            }
        }

        // free memory part
        for (int i = 0; i < nof; i++)
        {
            free(v1v2[i].list);
            v1v2[i].list = 0;
            v1v2[i].last = 0;
        }
    }
    free(v1v2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am initializing the allocated memory else where in my code, so there's no problem with the memory not being initialised. Thank YOu

Comment: I tried doing this by using free on remaining slots but the program crashed.

Comment: @MickeyJ: Incidentally, in your program, you have three separate calls to `malloc()`, and just one call to `free()`. That alone is indicative that there are leaks. As a quick rule of thumb, for each `malloc()`, there should be (just) one `free()`. Similarly with `calloc()`. For `realloc()`, the story is much more complicated, but if you only use it to alter previously allocated space, then you don't need a `free()` for the `realloc()` calls. (If you're perverse, you can use `realloc()` to free memory and to allocate ab initio. It's best not to be perverse, especially while learning.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand the code, it looks like when you `push`, because you use the pre-increment, the `.last` field actually holds the index of the last thing, not a count of how many have been pushed.  However, when you loop through to `free` them, you're looping while *less* than last, not less than or equal.

Comment: @ JCooper: I tried this but still there is memory leakage. Actually this is affecting the program because I am running this for several cases and therefore, I am pushing data onto the stack and then freeing memory and again pushing data and so on.... so for 1000 cases of this, there is huge memory leakage.

Comment: As Jonathan mentioned, the code snippet you gave doesn't initialize the memory.  Is that actually the case in your code?  It seems to me that when you cleaned-up the code to post, you introduced additional problems that make it hard to help you.  Perhaps you could edit the question and post the actual code?

Comment: Hm... but the malloc((20)) thing is still there.  Fix the things that have already been mentioned.  Then we can work on the remaining problems.